# Top Bar Drop Down not working in Foundation 6.2.4

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Trying to implement the dropdown on for the first time on this site, and have been having issues with it. Probably something I have missed but I've been looking at it for a while now and can't see what's wrong!

Below is a copy of the code on my page (Which I have copied from here: https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/top-bar.html)

```
      <div class="top-bar">

        <div class="top-bar-title">
<span data-responsive-toggle="responsive-menu" data-hide-for="medium" style="display: none;">
<button class="menu-icon dark" type="button" data-toggle=""></button>
</span>
            <Strong>Polaris CI Performance Board</Strong>
        </div>
        <div id="responsive-menu">
            <div class="top-bar-left">
                <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">One</a>
                        <ul class="menu vertical">
                            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="top-bar-right">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

As you can see from the screenshot the dropdown isn't compressing:
[image: Screenshot of index.html]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdown menu (or any component that uses JavaScript, which you can identify by the data-attributes) requires the Foundation JavaScript to be initialized on the page.  Your screenshot looks like this is not running... Make sure at the bottom of your `<body>` tag you have

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

See e.g. http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/installation.html#html-starter-template

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for that! :)